# Can't install lua xml trough luarocks

Tags: c++, xml, lua, luarocks

I'm trying to install `lua-requests` with [luarocks](https://luarocks.org), it requires `xml`, that fails to install.

Log says that C++17 can't work with `xml`, I tried to change it somehow, but I don't know how and where I should do it...

```
xml 1.1.3-1 depends on lua >= 5.1, < 5.4 (5.1-1 provided by VM)
xml 1.1.3-1 depends on lub >= 1.0.3, < 2 (1.0.7-1 installed)
gcc -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -c src/Parser.cpp -o src/Parser.o -Iinclude -Isrc/bind -Isrc/vendor
In file included from include/xml/Parser.h:33,
                 from src/Parser.cpp:1:
src/bind/dub/dub.h:298:48: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  298 | lua_Number checknumber(lua_State *L, int narg) throw(dub::TypeException);
      |                                                ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:299:50: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  299 | lua_Integer checkinteger(lua_State *L, int narg) throw(dub::TypeException);
      |                                                  ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:300:63: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  300 | const char *checklstring(lua_State *L, int narg, size_t *len) throw(dub::TypeException);
      |                                                               ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:301:82: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  301 | void **checkudata(lua_State *L, int ud, const char *tname, bool keep_mt = false) throw(dub::Exception);
      |                                                                                  ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:304:82: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  304 | void **checksdata(lua_State *L, int ud, const char *tname, bool keep_mt = false) throw(dub::Exception);
      |                                                                                  ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:307:62: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  307 | void **checksdata_d(lua_State *L, int ud, const char *tname) throw(dub::Exception);
      |                                                              ^~~~~
src/bind/dub/dub.h:317:56: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  317 | inline const char *checkstring(lua_State *L, int narg) throw(dub::TypeException) {
      |                                                        ^~~~~
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the error part(remove the throw) code, and use luarocks to make it.

example for modified error part.

```
lua_Number checknumber(lua_State *L, int narg) throw(dub::TypeException);
```

should be modified like this.

```
lua_Number checknumber(lua_State *L, int narg);
```

Here is my solution on **Amazon Linux 2023**.

```
cd ~
luarocks unpack xml
cd ~/xml-1.1.3-1/xml
# modify error file(src/bind/dub/dub.h, src/bind/dub/dub.cpp),
# remove the throw part.
luarocks make xml-1.1.3-1.rockspec
```

and xml will be installed

Answer (score 0):

Same problem is reported in lua-requests [bug reporter](https://github.com/JakobGreen/lua-requests/issues/33). There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/lubyk/xml/pull/20) to fix this issue in [xml library](https://github.com/lubyk/xml), but it was last updated 8 years ago and it looks like it is no longer maintained and original author is no longer active.

You can either modify source code as specified in pull request, or update .luarocks file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/lubyk/xml/issues/19#issuecomment-1399366115). Basically you just need to compile it with C++14 standard.